# Why did Spanish nationalists interrupt one-minute silence for the victims of Morocco earthquake?

Tags: international-relations, spain, nationalism, morocco

In [this](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20230911-spanish-protestors-disrupt-minute-silence-for-morocco/) link you will watch a video of Spanish nationalists in Catalonia who interrupted a minute moment of silence that was held for victims of the recent earthquake.

What's the reason these Spanish nationalists disrupted the moment of silence?

Comment: I have edited the question to remove opinions about the matter. Feel free to revert the change, but it would risk being closed for the "primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause".

Comment: Nitpick: "Catalonian nationalists" is kind of ambiguous and might seem to imply supporters for the independence of Catalonia. It national press it was reported that it was linked to far-right groups *against* the independence of Catalonia, and in fact the flag the wave is the Spanish one (although I am pretty sure many of them would have prefered the pre-Constituional version).

Comment: Is there any accompanying article with the details? How do we know this is actually a one-minute silence for the victims of the earthquake rather than just some persons standing around for some unknown purpose?

Comment: @user103496 https://www.lavanguardia.com/local/barcelona/20230910/9217298/collboni-lamenta-boicot-minuto-silencio-victimas-terremoto-marruecos.html, https://www.europapress.es/videos/video-manifestantes-contra-amnistia-interrumpen-minuto-silencio-marruecos-barcelona-20230910171620.html (links in Spanish)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clarify the situation, which isn't well described in your link.

The minute silence was organised by Barcelona City council and mayor, to remember the lives lost in the Morocco earthquake (Barcelona has a large Moroccan population).  The protestors are from a *Spanish* nationalist group and opposed to Catalan independence. They are waving flags of Spain and the Civil Guard (a branch of the army that provides police services)  They are protesting against the Mayor and his suggestion that the former President of Catalonia be pardoned. They are chanting "Puigdemont to prison". This protest is not directly aimed at the Moroccans. It's unclear if it was timed to coincide with the act or remembrance.

Why did they continue their protest during the minute's silence?  One can only speculate.  Perhaps they thought that it would bring greater attention to their protest. Perhaps it is because they knew that the Mayor would be present. Perhaps they wanted to insult immigrant Moroccans.  Perhaps it was just self-centred rudeness - they just thought that their protest was more important.  Perhaps it was a mixture of these. Perhaps it was the folly of the crowd. It is merely speculation. There's no reason to suppose each protestor had the same reasons.

Comment: Spain's elimination by Morocco in 2022 FIFA World Cup can be another possible reason I think.

Comment: why? The protestors aren't shouting anti morocco things.  They are protesting against the mayor of Barcelona